# Apache Tomcat 8 and Geoexplorer

Tags: installation, geoexplorer, tomcat

I have Apache Tomcat 8.0 and GeoServer 2.6 on Windows 7.

I have placed GeoExplorer folder into webbapp (The files web.xml and weblogic are included) as described, but it does not work!

Apache Tomcat works properly, GeoServer too, but GeoExplorer does not.

Please could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug that makes that geoserver fails if deployed in tomcat 8.0.24 (but works with version 8.0.23 o below)

Also it's fixed in tomcat 8.0.25. [Check this bug ticket](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58192) and review if your log output is the same.